# How can we access an element of a vector which of user defined data type. Is their any special method as traditional method is not working

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am stuck on one question of Data Structure and algorithm. The question is about how to construct a Binary Search Tree (BST) of minimum height from a given BST. For more clarity, here is the link to the question

[Convert a normal BST to Balanced BST](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-normal-bst-balanced-bst/)

Here is my solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    TreeNode *left, *right;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this->val = data;
        this->right = NULL;
        this->left = NULL;
    }
};

void inorder_traversal(TreeNode *root, vector<TreeNode*> &v1)// Inorder traversal of tree
{
    if(!root)
        return;
    inorder_traversal(root->left, v1);
    v1.push_back(root);
    inorder_traversal(root->right, v1);
}

TreeNode* conversion(vector<TreeNode*> &v1, int start, int end) //
{
   if(start > end)
       return NULL;
   int mid = (start + end) / 2;
   //-----------Doubt Part----------//
  v1[mid]->left = conversion(v1, start, mid - 1);// I think this part is not working well
  v1[mid]->right = conversion(v1, mid + 1, end);
  return v1[mid];
  //-------------------------------//
}

void solve(TreeNode *root) // main function 
{
    vector<TreeNode*> v1;
    inorder_traversal(root, v1);// function to get the inorder traversal of the given tree
    int n = v1.size();
    cout << v1.size();
    TreeNode *l = conversion(v1, 0, n);// function to convert given tree to min height BST
    for(auto itr : v1)
        cout << itr->val << " ";
}

int height(TreeNode *root) // function to calculate the height of the BST tree
{
    if(!root)
        return 0;
    int hl = height(root->left);
    int hr = height(root->right);
    return 1 + max(hl, hr);
}

int main()
{
    TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(10);
    root->left = new TreeNode(8);
    root->left->left = new TreeNode(7);
    root->left->left->left = new TreeNode(6);
    root->left->left->left->left = new TreeNode(5);
    int height1 = height(root);
    solve(root);
    int height2 = height(root);
    cout << "Initial height before the conversion :" << height1 << "\n";
    cout << "Final height after the conversion :" << height2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I am not getting any output after executing the current code, and I figured that the problem has occurred because of the **Doubt part** of my code.

Can anyone please help me with this code?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please [never include that header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: More related to your question, have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? For example to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch any possible crashes, and locate when and where in your code it happens?

Comment: Use a debugger to pinpoint the problem instead of asking people to find out the problem for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sure that the conflicting part of my code is the doubt part but I not know how to solve it

Comment: After some recursions, `start` and `end` are both `5` resulting in `mid` also being `5` and `v1[mid]` has undefined behaviour as `v1` only has 5 elements

Comment: By the way, that site (geeksforgeeks), isn't really a good teaching or learning resource, despite what it and others might claim. It teaches bad habits, bad code, and sometimes even *invalid* code. If you really want to learn C++ please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take computer-science classes.

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for your suggestion . Also can you tell me some good debuggers

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks man for your wonderful advice .I will  surely try them

Comment: On windows I use visual studio, on other platforms lldb or gdb usually via VS code

Comment: The traditional method is working perfectly well and is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. It is not the method.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you don't know what `end` means in your code. You need to decide. Is it the index of the last element of the range, or one past that?

If it the index of the last element of the range, then `conversion(v1, 0, n)` is wrong (should be `conversion(v1, 0, n-1)`).

If it is one past that, then `if (start > end)` is wrong (should be `if (start >= end)`), and `conversion(v1, start, mid - 1)` is wrong too (left as an exercise).

Note in C++ `end` by convention means "one past the range". If you want the "last index" meaning, call your indices `first` and `last`.

Another problem is that what was the root before the conversion is no longer the root after the conversion. `solve` has the new root for a brief moment, but then throws it away and returns nothing, so `main` has the wrong root.